# Cascade delete one-to-many with one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having problems deleting an entity of EntityB due to EntityA having a relation to RelationAB in the list.

I am having no trouble deleting RelationAB by removing it from the list, but I want to be able to delete EntityB in one transaction.

Is it possible to somehow delete EntityB, cascade delete RelationAB and remove RelationAB from EntityA.EntityBs as well?

```
public class EntityA : Entity {
    List<RelationAB> EntityBs {get; set;}
}

public class EntityB : Entity {
}

public class RelationAB : Entity {
    public EntityA EntityA {get; set;}
    public EntityA EntityAId {get; set;}
    public EntityB EntityB {get; set;}
    public EntityB EntityBId {get; set;}
}

public class RelationABConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<RelationAB>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RelationAB> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(RelationAB));

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.EntityA)
            .WithMany(x => x.EntityBs)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EntityAId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        builder
            .HasOne(x => x.EntityB)
            .WithMany()
            .IsRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EntityBId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe making your properties nullable can solve this problem.